# Feature Toggling for apps (for a/b testing)

Tags: testing

I have a published app (Android/iOS) and I'd like to instrument the next version so that I can remotely enable/disable or adjust features, through a web interface. This could facilitate a/b testing for example.

I'm struggling with this because I don't know what this concept is called (remote feature control?, feature flagging?), so it's hard for me to search for solutions. I'm hoping there are services out there that provide a web interface for controlling simple key-value pairs for my app on the fly, possibly allowing for cohorts. I've searched through the docs for crittercism, localytics, google docs and haven't found anything.

At runtime my app would rely on that service's sdk code to query the server-set value of such a parameter and act accordingly. For example, the app might use the value 500 milliseconds for an animation based on a key called ANIMATION_DURATION.

Any advice on terminology or examples of such services would be much appreciated. Thanks.

As I'm writing this, I just found a company called Airwatch. They call their solution "Enterprise Mobility Management", so maybe that's one example.

Comment: did you find anything ? I am looking for this answer too.

Comment: Localytics advertises a/b testing but I don't think their stuff is fully-baked yet. So we are evaluating another product called Artisan.
Please upvote this question so others will be more likely to find it.

Comment: Apparently "Feature Toggle" or "Feature Flagging" is the term for this. Here is a wiki article on the subject: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_toggle
I'm now considering a company called Apptimize which advertises support for a/b testing.

Comment: I've found "feature toggle" more commonly used for the closely related concept of including code to turn off support on a per-build basis for features that are not yet finished. The idea is to simplify development by avoiding the need for version control branches but still allow you to release a new version without finishing all outstanding work.

Comment: Here is a related post from SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20301353/are-there-any-good-strategies-for-a-b-testing-on-mobile-devices

Comment: @JosephJohnson, Have you found a solution, since posting?

Comment: Yes, we are using Apptimize, which is a paid service. We integrated their sdk into our app and now use it to toggle features post-release.

Comment: @JosephJohnson, Does that service communicate back to you the testing data gathered within your instrumented app?

Comment: Yes my app communicates info back to me based on user reaction to my experiment. There is a dashboard on the Apptimize website where I can 'start an experiment' (basically means activate some pre-defined code). For example: if I have instrumented my code to react to an Apptimize custom field called "IntroImage", then post-release I can use the Apptimize dashboard to start the "IntroImage" experiment. Then I can watch the data and see if a goal (a sale for example) was reached more often for cohort A (using introA.png) or cohort B (using introB.png).

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing such testing, you will need a way to **get the result data back** to you. Feature toggling services won't necessarily provide such two-way communication. It seems as though you will need a two-way communication channel, and probably some kind of registration or log-in, such as by having a http server and requiring some frequency of communication from the app. (not necessarily constant connection, but frequent enough for your desire to change settings and retrieve test data.)